# Set up network without router

Tags: networking, wireless, router

my Dad, who's 88, had a pretty useless laptop (it was a 4Mb Celeron, running Windows 10, via Microsoft's unwanted, irreversible auto-upgrade/install). Too slow, pathetic GUI. While it was running, I noted down the details for the (wireless network) router: network name (Plusnet default) and router pass key.

Then I took the laptop away and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. A vast improvement. Now I want to add his wireless network to the laptop before packing it up and posting it back to him (my Dad), who lives 340 miles away. Adding the wireless network will, unfortunately, be beyond him, so I have to do it;  without the router to which it will be connected (yes, I should have brought that with me too...).

So, I know the network name and the pass key. If I install a network with those details, will Ubuntu automatically connect when it's booted up in the presence of the router?

And yes, I know I'm dumb. Long drive, had to pack in a hurry.

Thanks for reading, and in advance for any help.

Cheers

John M.

Comment: i completed my answer. Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

**Easy**
Assuming that:

```
WiFi network name is    : MyWiFi
Encryption is           : WPA2
WiFi network adapter is : wlan0 (check it with iwconfig)
```

You must adapt this according to your information, hope that you have them right.

You can write a script that will have to be lauched by you Dad, as normal user
You can create a launcher on the desktop to make it easy to use

The Script: (you should try one with your own WiFi)

```
# Create connection profile wifi-net
nmcli con add wifi-net MyWiFi ifname wlan0 type wifi ssid MyWiFi
# Set a WPA2 password, for example “caffeandcake”
nmcli con modify wifi-net wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli con modify wifi-net wifi-sec.psk caffeandcake
nmcli con modify wifi-net autoconnect true
# Activate
nmcli radio wifi off
nmcli radio wifi on
nmcli connection up wifi-net
```

**Better but stronger**

-1- Create a WiFi connection with your WiFi
-2- Modify the connection profile file to match the target WiFi network

If you dont have all the needed informations like the mac address of the WiFi AP, it is a no go.

You may find the connection profile file there :
`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

And edit it with
`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

You will have to change the following

```
id
seen-bssids
ssid
[wifi-security] section, with encryption type and encryption key
```

i hope you have all needed informations...